# 14.04 Unable to install correct package

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, libraries

I'm attempting to configure an oculus rift for this I need to execture
  `./OculusConfigUtil_i386`

This gives me the following error:

```
./OculusConfigUtil_i386: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386
sudo apt-get install libudev0
```

both eturned that the packagep(:i386) has no installation candidate.

[This worked for me,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496028/package-libdconf0-has-no-installation-candidate) but gave me the error:

```
./OculusConfigUtil_i386: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when trying to run the script again.
any ideas?

Running:

```
ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libudev
```

Gives this output:

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 jul 22 09:56 libudev.so.0 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 jun 20 02:15 libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.3.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67600 jun 20 02:16 libudev.so.1.3.5
```

Comment: So you have installed libudev.so.1?

Comment: I have installed libdconf1, sudo apt-get install libudev.so.1 also returns unable to locate package libudev.so.1

Comment: `locate` is not updated instantly, run `sudo updatedb` to update it.

Comment: Nope still the same problem sudo updatedb runs fine (no return value just runs) but all other installs still fail and so does the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install libudev1` if `libudev.so.1` is not already installed then:

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Comment: Well I have libdconf1 (in the linked question) but don't have libudev.so.1 which when I run sudo apt-get install libudev.so.1 returns E: Unable to locate package libudev.so.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libudev.so.1'

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libudev1` is the command you need to run.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libudev1 returned 17 not upgraded and the rest unchanged sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 returned nothing and the script still doesn't run same error

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libudev` please.

Comment: I put the output in the OP

Comment: Output looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes but the script isn't working so am I doing something wrong here? Is the script wrong?

Comment: Ah found it should have made sure the script was also in 64 bits not 32 bits thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded the `libudev0` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libudev0 and then install like this:
`sudo dpkg -i libudev0_175-0ubuntu9.10_amd64.deb`.
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, you can do it this way:

```
sudo aptitude install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 liborbit-2-0:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libgnomevfs2-0:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libsm6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxt6:i386 libasound2:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libudev0:i386
```